# Можно ли отсортировать массив int-ов на этапе его заполнения? И есть ли в этом какой-нибудь смысл?

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Я считываю массив int-ов из файла, и мне точно придется отсортировать его в будущем. Будет ли быстрее использовать какую-то сортировку на этапе заполнения массива?

Comment: Сортируя на этапе построения вы отсекаете целый пласт алгоритмов сортировки, но если входящие данные почти отсортированы, то это наверно может дать какой то прирост.

Comment: Чтение элемента из файла - заведомо более медленная, чем вставка элемента в сортированный массив, операция. Т.е. дополнительные операции по сортировке на фоне времени дисковых операций скорее всего просто потеряются..

Comment: В общем случае, если входные данные случайны, получится сравнимая сложность O(N log N) -- для N значений будет применяться двоичный поиск и вставка.  Однако, если известен диапазон входных значений и он относительно невелик (например, байтовые значения 0-255), можно применить сортировку подсчётом со сложностью O(N).

Comment: Применять сортировку на этапе добавления данных в массив нету смысла, потому что усложняется понимание кода, а так же шансы допустить ошибку вырастают.
Чем сложнее алгоритм, тем выше вероятность, что в нём ошибка.

Поэтому самый просто способ это сделать сортировку после формирования массива данных. 
Так у Вас получится разграничить логику выполнения и код будет понятнее  и алгоритм сам проще.

Comment: Можно складывать числа не в массив, а в `TreeSet`, скажем. Если нужен именно массив, потом конвертировать его в массив, а если нет, обходить итератором. Будет ли быстрее -- вопрос тёмный, нужно мерить

Comment: Сортировка потом всегда будет быстрее сортировки в процессе загрузки данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не думаю, что сортировка при добавлении даст прирост в скорости.
Мои тесты показали, что при генерации и заполнении массива 500.000 элементами и использовании java.util.Arrays.sort() массив работает в 2-2.5 раза быстрее, чем при использование TreeSet с дальнейшем приведением его к массиву.
При увеличении же массива до 5.000.000 разница в скорости увеличивается в 13 раз в пользу массива. Во времени это около 500мс, против 6500мс.
Так же стоит учесть накладные расходы, если размер массива заранее известен то проблем нет, иначе вам придется создавать массивы "с запасом". Как вариант, можно использовать классы интерфейса List. Их скорость работы в 2 раза лучше чем TreeSet, но все же достаточно медленно по сравнению с массивами.

Мой ответ немного не точен. Дело в том, что я генерировал значения с помощью Random и заполнял ими коллекции.
Привел тесты к тому состоянию как вам нужно, теперь я считываю данные из файла. Результаты получились немного другими.

Для файла на 500000 элементов время затраченное на считывание и сортировку в в мс.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А тут время затраченное для обработки 50000000 элементов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]